# pytorch DataLoader very slow when dataset is big and shuffle is True

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a big dataset with lots of images and I found that the speed of dataloader is very slow.
I did many tests and found when the number of images is big:

1. Direct read the dataset is fast
2. Set shuffle = False with num_workers=0, also fast (1.1 times slower than 1st one)
3. Set shuffle = False with num_workers=8, becomes slow (2.8 times slower than 1st one)
4. Set shuffle = True with num_workers=0, slower (7.2 times slower than 1st one)
5. Set shuffle = True with num_workers=8,(9.2 times slower than 1st one)

Here is the sample code:

```
class MyTestDataset(torchvision.datasets.vision.VisionDataset):
    def __init__(self, 
                 transform=None,
                 target_transform=None):
        super(MyTestDataset, self).__init__(None, transform=transform,
                                          target_transform=target_transform)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        return np.random.rand(256, 256),random.randint(0, 300)

    def __len__(self):
        return 17250000
    
dataset = MyTestDataset()

since = time.time()
imgs = []
for idx in range(128):
    img,label = dataset[10000+idx*1000]
    imgs.append(img)
base = time.time() - since
print("next dataset",base)

loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
since = time.time()
imgs = next(iter(loader))
cost = time.time() - since
print("loader no shuffle num_workers-0",cost,cost/base)

loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, num_workers=8)
since = time.time()
imgs = next(iter(loader))
cost = time.time() - since
print("loader no shuffle num_workers-8",cost,cost/base)

loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
since = time.time()
imgs = next(iter(loader))
cost = time.time() - since
print("loader shuffle num_workers-0",cost,cost/base)

dataset = MyTestDataset()
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True, num_workers=8)
since = time.time()
imgs = next(iter(loader))
cost = time.time() - since
print("loader shuffle num_workers-8",cost,cost/base)
```

and below is the output

```
next dataset 0.2839939594268799
loader no shuffle num_workers-0 0.3133578300476074 1.103396109832709
loader no shuffle num_workers-8 0.811976432800293 2.859132759157693
loader shuffle num_workers-0 2.041795253753662 7.189572827091643
loader shuffle num_workers-8 2.617912769317627 9.218198776483705
```

Seems shuffle make it 9 times slow?

Comment: Shuffle a dataset of about 20 millions images will take time. It is normal. If you want to reduce time, you have to consider using `sampler` or `batch_sampler` params of the `DataLoader` class.

Comment: you are right, I have tested it again, and it = iter(loader) cost most of the time or only 1 inter cost much time, thanks.